# Couldn't find adb interface driver for colors x114?

Tags: android, windows-8, drivers

I wanted to run my android studio project in real android phone, and for that, I required adb interface driver software in windows 8 for my android phone which is Colors X114.I couldn't find it anywhere, not even in official website. So, where can I get it?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using wireless adb, Its very hard to find drivers for all devices. wifi adb works like a charm. Just search 'wireless adb' in play store and install any app (there are many in the app store) Follow the instructions in the app and you are good to go.

Comment: Do I have to root my android phone to use wifi adb?

Comment: You also need to root for using wired adb.